# JQuery: Select multiple select tags of a name

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to access all my select tags with a specific name.
I've tried doing this:

```
$("select[name='blah']")
```

and

```
$("select[name='blah[]']")
```

but neither are working.

I followed the JQuery documentation that showed it doing it like this for inputs:

```
$("input[name='newsletter']")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do your `<select>` tags look like?

Comment: Something else must be wrong, works like a charm. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/Gntff/

Comment: my select tags look like <select name="blah[" + i + "]>" where I is a number from 1 to how many selects the user chooses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update, based on your comment:* You should use an [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("select[name^='blah[']")
```

This will select any `<select name="blah[.........">` which should be specific enough for your needs.

Also, be sure you're running your selector inside a `document.ready` context like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("select[name='blah']").doSomething();
});
```

Without doing this, or after the element in question in the page, the element won't be there to select...so your selector may be just fine, but what it's looking for isn't in the DOM yet.  Putting your code in a `document.ready` handler like I have above ensures the DOM has all the elements ready to select.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Why did I have to use $("select[name^='blah[']")
 instead of the standard?

Comment: @2Real - The equals selector is an *exact* match, the literal string, but you have a variable in there, so a starts-with or a regex is a more appropriate here :)